# REST service is not working with $.Ajax() of type POST

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery, cordova

I am using REST service for POSTing data from my Cordova Application to server.
The same service works for **$.post()** but it's not working for **$.Ajax()** with type "POST".
Could anyone tell me WHY??

Comment: Can you post your full ajax coding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `type : 'POST'` for your Ajax method like below..

```
$.ajax({ type : 'POST', ....});
```

Comment: $.ajax({
   url : <ServiceURL>,
   data : JSON.stringify(JSonData),
   type : 'POST',
   contentType : "text/html",
   dataType : 'json',
   success : function(Result) {
   },
   headers: {
        "Authorization" :"Basic " + myBase64variable,
        "Content-Type" :"application/json"
    }
   error: function (RcvData, error) {
      console.log(RcvData);
   }
});

Comment: I think something problem in your Content-Type; maybe the second one that you add in your header is not necessary. however for get the proper reason install firebug or use google chrome developer tools to identify what really pass between client and server when you use &.post or when you use &.ajax.